# Is it possible to warp an image on html5 canvas?

Tags: html, canvas

I want to make an android app where you can warp a photo using your fingers. Something like this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rm.android.facewarp&hl=en

I would like to do so only using html5, css3 and javascript. Is it possible? And how can I do it?

Comment: It's definitely possible. Javascript is turing-complete.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this library will help: http://github.com/migurski/canvas-warp

Here is the demo of what it is capable of: http://jsdo.it/canvastag/y56M