# Copy a rectangle from a html canvas that is at an arbitary angle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas in HTML with an image, and a rectangle defined on the canvas by its four corners. I want to copy the image from the canvas into a new canvas. The difficulty comes that the rectangle will be at an arbitrary angle and so I cant simply use 'getImageData' as I had previously planned.

I basically need to write a function which takes a canvas and the four points and returns a canvas as illustrated in this image. I welcome any suggestions as to the best way to start.

[image: Image showing the process of copying a section of one canvas to a new image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a second canvas, apply a rotation transform, and draw your original image onto it.

In the demo below, the first canvas is your source image, and the second is your copied rectangle.

```js
// Create a demo canvas
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 200;
canvas.height = 150;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

// Draw an image on the demo canvas
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, canvas.height);
gradient.addColorStop(.4, 'cyan');
gradient.addColorStop(.4, 'yellow');
gradient.addColorStop(.6, 'blue');
gradient.addColorStop(.6, 'purple');
ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

getRect(canvas, 80, 60, 100, 50, -35 * Math.PI / 180);

function getRect(src, x, y, w, h, angle) {
  // Create a canvas for the rectangle's data
  const _canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  _canvas.width = w;
  _canvas.height = h;
  document.body.appendChild(_canvas);
  const _ctx = _canvas.getContext('2d');
  _ctx.translate(w / 2, h / 2);
  _ctx.rotate(-angle);
  _ctx.drawImage(src, -x, -y);
  
  // getImageData here from _canvas, if desired
  
  // Show an outline around the source rectangle
  ctx.translate(x, y);
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
  ctx.strokeRect(-w / 2, -h / 2, w, h);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Don't you find it strange that you never use`x` and `y` in your function?

Comment: @Kaiido you mean the `x` and `y` used here? `ctx.translate(x, y);`

Comment: @freedomn-m this part only draws the outline on the original canvas, the `x` and `y` variables are never used when the image has been drawn on the target canvas. This function works only when `x === src.width / 2` and `y === src.height / 2`.

Comment: @Kaiido good call.  So this solution *always* copies the centre of the source image.  I tried changing `/2` to `/3` for x,y and, as you say, it just moves the box while the "copied" image is still just the centre of the source.   Could do with an image rather than pattern - but otherwise appears to be a start rather than complete solution.

Comment: @Kaiido Good catch. I fixed the bug in the function.

Comment: Thank you - this really helped me in the right direction! I wont post my final solution as I think the example here is cleaner, but very grateful for your help! :-)

Answer (score -1):

You could use openCV and warpAffine.  I think there are web implementations of openCV these days (https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/d0a/tutorial_js_intro.html).  There may be another simpler library for this.  You're likely going to need and understanding of matrix transforms (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix).

Comment: See also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553787/is-it-possible-to-warp-an-image-on-html5-canvas

Comment: I am not sure it is needed to 'warp' the image as the rectangle is a true rectangle. I just need an algorithm to copy the pixels.

Comment: You need the transform to get the rotation, but yes it is not a affine warp.  That is likely the function you would use, but the canvas based solution above is far better with less dependencies.